# VS Code ignoring settings for pylint

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylint

I'm trying to disable certain pylint warnings from VS Code, but nothing I do seems to work. I have put the same settings in all 3 of the possible places (User, Remote, Workspace), but the command line shown in the pylint output window doesn't reflect it. I've tried restarting, disable/enabling the extension.  I am using Remote Explorer from my Window VSCode to a Linux server.  I've got almost everything else working, including remote debug.  I'm running python from a Virtual Environment.  But I can't surpress pylint errors/warnings.  Here is the setting I am trying:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--disable=C0103,C0303"
],
```

and this is what the pylint window shows:

```
/home/mlakata/e2e_ve/bin/python -m pylint --reports=n --output-format=json --from-stdin /home/mlakata/file1/file1.py
CWD Linter: /home/mlakata
file:///home/mlakata/File1/File1.py :
[
    {
        "type": "convention",
        "module": "File1",
        "obj": "",
        "line": 19,
        "column": 47,
        "endLine": null,
        "endColumn": null,
        "path": "File1/File1.py",
        "symbol": "trailing-whitespace",
        "message": "Trailing whitespace",
        "message-id": "C0303"
    },
... several hundred more warnings ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Pylint behaves rather unintuitively about where it takes its config from.

Two things are key to keep in mind:

1. IDEs often run pylint from a *sub-directory* (namely, from the directory directly containing the python file to be linted).
2. If pylint is being run from a sub-directory, this often changes which config file is being used, because pylint uses a weird order of priority ([as stated here](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/usage/run.html#command-line-options)).

As a result, I would say there are three main gotchas:

- Gotcha 1: `pyproject.toml` or `setup.cfg` don't get respected at all when running pylint from a sub-directory.
- Gotcha 2: On the other hand, a `pylintrc` or `.pylintrc` in an upper directory *will* get respected, if the current working directory is a python package.
- Gotcha 3: Some long-forgotten `pylintrc` or `.pylintrc` file lying around in your user's home or configuration directories might be running the show without your knowing.

To solve any issue similar to yours, it can be very helpful to run pylint with the `--verbose` flag, because then it tells you where it takes its config from.