# pylint gives error when run by tox, but not otherwise

Tags: python, pylint, tox

I have been adding pylint and tox to a simple project: https://github.com/rrthomas/rpl/tree/tox

When I run pylint on my code, with some warnings turned off, I get no errors:

```
$ pylint --disable=C,fixme,too-many-locals,too-many-branches,too-many-statements rpl

-------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 9.68/10, +0.32)
```

However, when I run the same pylint command with tox, it gives me errors:

```
$ tox -e py310
...
py310 run-test: commands[2] | pylint --disable=C,fixme,too-many-locals,too-many-branches,too-many-statements rpl
************* Module rpl
rpl:356:11: E1101: Module 'regex' has no 'MULTILINE' member (no-member)
rpl:356:30: E1101: Module 'regex' has no 'IGNORECASE' member (no-member)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 9.68/10 (previous run: 9.68/10, +0.00)
```

I'm using the identical version of pylint both with and without tox.

I'm baffled, and I don't know whether I've done something wrong, or whether there's some problem, in which case, whose fault is it?

Comment: Well, thanks to everyone helping me, you pushed me to look more closely at the library versions, and it seems I'm using a different version of `regex` in the two cases, and this accounts for the discrepancy between the outputs. Sorry for claiming that I was using identical versions of everything everywhere, and thanks very much for your helpful guesses.

Answer (score 0):

tox runs the tests in isolation. I'd guess tox is not moving the pylint configuration file so the pylint configuration is not automatically detected anymore by pylint. Try using the `--rcfile` option to specify the configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! There is no pylint configuration file, though.

Comment: On second lecture, pylint does not take .pyi into account.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, it seems I was looking in the wrong place for the problem. So, I still cannot see what is different about the two runs of pylint so that in one case it gives no error and in the other case it gives an error. I have removed the mention of `.pyi` files from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `--verbose` flag to the pylint command which is run by tox. Then it tells you which configuration file is actually being used during the execution. The result is often rather unexpected.

I've written a bit more about the background [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73997240/17093315) (albeit in a somewhat different context) .

Comment: Thanks very much for this hint! In my case, it says "No config file found, using default configuration" for both the run under tox, and the run without tox.

Comment: Okay, then the problem seems to be something entirely different. Somebody once got the same error message (not with tox though); they wrote that it seems to have to do with the fact that the `regex` package creates its members `MULTILINE` and `IGNORECASE` *dynamically*, so that pylint's inference system doesn't see them: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Kigv8_iqI-QJ:https://www.kianmeng.org/2022/04/e1101-module-regex-has-no-multiline.html&cd=2&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de That's as far as I can help you. :)

Comment: Thanks, @DavidSchulz, and I believe that the correct fix here is not to use the (backwards-compatible) global flags in regex, but the new `RegexFlag` class. This fixes the problem with pylint, though sadly it then exposes the fact that the mypy `.pyi` stubs in `types-regex` have not been updated (despite the version number matching exactly), and so mypy is now unhappy…but I can now see where the problem is and whose fault it is!